Did Mazinger ever use a Spazer other than in Grendizer U?
In the last episode of Grendizer U, they made Mazinger use a Spazer, an addon that was made for Grendizer.
Did Mazinger ever use a Spazer other than in Grendizer U, or this is the first time they do so?

Are you asking if Mazinger ever used one of Grendizer's Spazer modules specifically or if Mazinger ever had something that compares to Grendizer's Spazers? If the latter... does the Jet Scrander qualify?
